# How to solve new/updated file python list problem

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension, python-3.6

I want to store the file name and modified date timestamp in a list of lists format in Python 3.6 for a particular folder.

Suppose on day 1 I have two files in the folder, so I have the following list of lists:

```
day_1_List = [["f1", "2019-03-27T07:36:45Z"], ["f2", "2019-03-31T07:36:45Z"]]
```

Now, in day 2 another new file "f3" is created (new inner list added) and an existing file "f2" is updated (timestamp change):

```
day_2_List = [["f1", "2019-03-27T07:36:45Z"], ["f2", "2019-04-01T12:23:18Z"], ["f3", "2019-04-02T07:36:45Z"]]
```

I want to run a logic among the two lists, which will produce a simple list which will give me the names which needs a fresh pull.

```
output = ["f2", "f3"]
```

And also updating the day 1 list of lists with the newly added ones (keeping those files' inner lists which are deleted during the latest comparison.

Previously it was simple, my scope was only till new files, so I maintained a simple list of file names and did the below operation to get the newly added files:

```
delta = [item for item in new_list if item not in file_list]
```

Any help?

Comment: It seems more usefull to prepare a dict, with key=filename and value=data

Comment: I thought of the same. Can you suggest which would be more efficient in terms of processing time? @Wonka

Comment: acces with cost (1) by filename to update the date. With d.keys() you will get the list of filenames. You can also have a list as value to have a historic of modifications dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by building dicts out of your lists, that makes searching for the relevant filenames more efficient:

```
day_1_List = [["f1", "2019-03-27T07:36:45Z"], ["f2", "2019-03-31T07:36:45Z"]]
day_2_List = [["f1", "2019-03-27T07:36:45Z"], ["f2", "2019-04-01T12:23:18Z"], ["f3", "2019-04-02T07:36:45Z"]]

day1 = {filename:time for filename, time in day_1_List}
day2 = {filename:time for filename, time in day_2_List}

delta = [filename for filename in day2 if filename not in day1 or day1[filename]<day2[filename]]
print(delta)
# ['f2', 'f3']
```

You can also build a dict of the common, unchanged files between day 1 and day 2:

```
common = {filename: time for filename, time in day2.items() if day1.get(filename) == time}
print(common)
# {'f1': '2019-03-27T07:36:45Z'}
```

Comment: Even I was dubious between dict and list. Thanks for the suggestion. I also need an output which will give me all the common keys and timestamps from the latest file for all those common as well as the newly added ones (this is for updating the record keeping JSON file (dictionary) to be used as day_3_dict.

Comment: I added an example of how you can build a dict of unchanged files.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a dictionary, you can modified your code with something like this

```
delta = [item[0] for item in new_list if item[0] not in file_list and item[1] > date_cutoff]
```

And I would suggest to also convert `item[1]` to a datetime object for the comparison.

Comment: Already doing so, didn't add to the question as its already bulky:

Eg:
from dateutil import parser
dt1 = parser.parse("2019-03-27T07:36:45Z")
dt2 = parser.parse(dt2)
print(dt2 > dt1)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to choose only the 1st entry in your inner list like so

```
delta = [item[0] for item in day_2_List if item not in day_1_List]
```

**Note:** This will only help if you can ensure that day_2_list 'f2' only has data time which is higher then day_1_list to begin with.